# How to Split a String into Several Portions

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app that summarizes text messages that are sent to clients from Financial services provider, a text message is sent as a notification each time a user makes a transaction. 
Here is a sample message

> [-ZAAD SHILLING-] Ref:1141125019 SLSH4,000 sent to AXMED  XASAN
>   WARSAME(634458520) at 12/05/19 22:33:03, Your Balance is
>   SLSH44,222.62.

So I want to extract several portions of this message like

Ref:1141125019
Amount Sent: SLSH4,000
Recipient Name: AXMED  XASAN WARSAME
Recipient Phone: 634458520
Date: 12/05/19
Time: 22:33:03 
Balance: SLSH44,222.62

I have already got the text messages to appear in a listview, I now want to customize it, I don't want the whole message to appear, I just want the portion I mentioned above to appear.

Here is a Sample Code

```
  if (Data.contains("Ref:")){
                    String[] Tx = Data.split("Ref:");
                    String TxID = Tx[1];
}
```

Comment: Read about regular expressions in Java. That's the most simple and very powerful tool for such string parsing. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: This seems like the perfect job for regex

Answer (score 0):

This problem would probably be best solved using regular expressions (regex)

Regular expressions allow you to match a string based on a pattern, and extract information from the string.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "( [-ZAAD SHILLING-] Ref:1141125019 SLSH4,000 sent to AXMED XASAN WARSAME(634458520) at 12/05/19 22:33:03, Your Balance is SLSH44,222.62. )";

        String headerReg = "\\[-([a-zA-Z\\s]+?)-]";
        String refReg = "Ref:([0-9]+)";
        String amountReg = "([,.\\w]+)";
        String nameReg = "([\\w\\s]+?)";
        String accountReg = "\\([0-9]+\\)";
        String dateReg = "([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})";
        String timeReg = "([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})";
        String balanceReg = "([,.\\w]+?)";

        String finalReg = "\\( " + headerReg + " " + refReg + " " + amountReg + " sent to " + nameReg + accountReg + " at " + dateReg + " " + timeReg + ", Your Balance is " + balanceReg + ". \\)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(finalReg);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            MatchResult result = matcher.toMatchResult();
            int groups = result.groupCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
                System.out.println(result.group(i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this, we can find the relevant data from your input string.

Answer (score 0):

If the message syntax is always the same then you can use some tricky split strings like this:

```
    String msg = "( [-ZAAD SHILLING-] Ref:1141125019 SLSH4,000 sent to AXMED XASAN WARSAME(634458520) at 12/05/19 22:33:03, Your Balance is SLSH44,222.62. )";
    String ref = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split(" ")[0];
    String amount = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split(" ")[1].split(" ")[0];
    String recipient = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split("sent to ")[1].split("\\(")[0];
    String phone = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split("sent to ")[1].split("\\(")[1].split("\\)")[0];
    String date = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split("sent to ")[1].split("\\(")[1].split(" at ")[1].split(" ")[0];
    String time = msg.split("Ref:")[1].split("sent to ")[1].split("\\(")[1].split(" at ")[1].split(" ")[1].split(",")[0];
    String balance = msg.split("Your Balance is ")[1].split("\\)")[0];

    System.out.println("ref: "+ref);
    System.out.println("amount: "+amount);
    System.out.println("recipient: "+recipient);
    System.out.println("phone: "+phone);
    System.out.println("date: "+date);
    System.out.println("time: "+time);
    System.out.println("balance: "+balance);
```

Result is:

```
ref: 1141125019
amount: SLSH4,000
recipient: AXMED XASAN WARSAME
phone: 634458520
date: 12/05/19
time: 22:33:03
balance: SLSH44,222.62.
```